# In React Native, how do I put a view on top of another view, with part of it lying outside the bounds of the view behind?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make a layout as per below with React Native.

[image]

How do I specify the position of B relative to A?

With iOS Interface Builder and autoconstraints, this can very explicitly be done and is a breeze. It's not so obvious how one might achieve this with React Native.

Comment: A simple `zIndex: 100` on the "floating view" worked for me in my situation.

Comment: the right combination of `zIndex:10` and a negative margin `marginTop:-15` should get you what you want. *position:'absolute' might mess things up* on bigger screens take that into account, possibly avoid it.

Comment: I'd recommend using this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65676669/14987294

Answer (score 125):

Add the following style to the "floating" view:

```
position: 'absolute'
```

You may also need to add a `top` and `left` value for positioning.

Comment: It's also important that the `view B` must come after `view A` in the hierarchy, as there is no `zIndex` support for now.

Comment: How would this work across different display sizes and aspect ratios?

Comment: @hitmaneidos you can do bottom: -15. However, this doesn't solve a problem if B is on top of 2 views (imagine white space below as view C). In that case view B has to come after A and C and with both A and C being of variable height I can't come up with a solution without manually calculating the height of each view...

Answer (score 22):

The above solutions were not working for me. I solved it by creating a View with the same background colour as the parent and added negative margin to move the image upwards.

```
<ScrollView style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
  <View
    style={{
      width: '95%',
      paddingLeft: '5%',
      marginTop: 80,
      height: 800,
    }}>
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>

      <Thumbnail square large source={{uri: uri}} style={{ marginTop: -30 }}/>
      <Text>Some Text</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

and I got the following result.

[image]

Answer (score 17):

You can use `zIndex` for placing a view on top of another. It works like the CSS z-index property - components with a larger `zIndex` will render on top.

You can refer: [Layout Props](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#zindex.)

Snippet:

```
    <ScrollView>
          <StatusBar backgroundColor="black" barStyle="light-content" />
          <Image style={styles.headerImage} source={{ uri: "http://www.artwallpaperhi.com/thumbnails/detail/20140814/cityscapes%20buildings%20hong%20kong_www.artwallpaperhi.com_18.jpg" }}>
            <View style={styles.back}>
              <TouchableOpacity>
                <Icons name="arrow-back" size={25} color="#ffffff" />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <Image style={styles.subHeaderImage} borderRadius={55} source={{ uri: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/Albert_Einstein_1947.jpg/220px-Albert_Einstein_1947.jpg" }} />
          </Image>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "white"
    },
    headerImage: {
        height: height(150),
        width: deviceWidth
    },
    subHeaderImage: {
        height: 110,
        width: 110,
        marginTop: height(35),
        marginLeft: width(25),
        borderColor: "white",
        borderWidth: 2,
        zIndex: 5
    },
```

Comment: Correct Layout Props reference url - https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props#zindex

Answer (score 14):

You can use this `OverlayContainer`. The trick is to use `absolute` with `100%` size. Check below an example:

```
// @flow

import React from 'react'
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

type Props = {
  behind: React.Component,
  front: React.Component,
  under: React.Component
}

// Show something on top of other
export default class OverlayContainer extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    const { behind, front, under } = this.props

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.center}>
          <View style={styles.behind}>
            {behind}
          </View>
          {front}
        </View>
        {under}
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  center: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  behind: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
  }
})
```

Comment: are you sure you meant `height: 100,` and not `height: '100%',` ?

Comment: I don't even remember commenting here last year, but it seems this is (at least) the second time this answer is super helpful to me - thank you very much again! :-)
In my case, the `front` view is an `Animated.View`; I had to remove `alignItems: 'center' from `styles.center`, otherwise it wouldn't show up.

Answer (score 13):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';


export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <View>// you need to wrap the two Views an another View
          <View style={styles.box1}></View>
          <View style={styles.box2}></View>
       </View> 
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  box1:{
    height:100,
    width:100,
    backgroundColor:'red'
  },
  box2:{
    height:100,
    width:100,
    backgroundColor:'green',
    position: 'absolute',
    top:10,
    left:30

  },
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `react-native-view-overflow` plugin for placing a view on top of another. It works like the CSS z-index property.

```
import ViewOverflow from 'react-native-view-overflow';

<ViewOverflow />
    <View style={[styles2.cardBox, { marginTop: 50 }]}>
    <View style={[styles2.cardItem]} >
      <Text style={styles2.cardHeader}>userList</Text>
    </View>
      <View style={[styles2.cardContent]}>
        <Text style={styles2.text}>overflow: "visible"</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={[styles2.cardItemFooter]} >
        <Text style={styles2.cardTextFooter}>...</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </ViewOverflow>

const styles2 = StyleSheet.create({
  cardBox: {
    borderLeftWidth: 0,
    borderTopWidth: 0,
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#d0d0d0",
    width: '94%',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    height: 200,
    position: "relative",
    borderRadius: 15,
    overflow: "visible" // doesn't do anything
  },
  cardContent: {
    textAlign: "right",
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    marginTop: 15,
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    padding: 5,
  },
  cardHeader: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontFamily: 'Vazir',
    fontSize: 12
  },
  cardItem: {
    backgroundColor: "#3c4252",
    borderRadius: 3,
    position: "absolute",
    top: -10,
    right: -5,
    width: 50,
    height: 20,
    paddingRight: 5,
  },
})
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing to StackOverflow. To make this a better answer, please format the code section correctly and add an explanation or link to documentation for the necessary methods used. You could also consider putting up code snippets that can be executed via jsFiddle.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the example [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54108708/1433372) i've created a component which stacks all childeren on top of each other. You could even nest OverlayContainers inside OverlayContainers.

Usage:

```
<OverlayContainer>
    <View style={{backgroundColor:'red', width:150, height: 150}}></View>
    <View style={{backgroundColor:'yellow', width:50, height: 50}}></View>
    <Text>Just some text</Text>
</OverlayContainer>
```

Output:

[image: Output]

```
import React, { FC, PropsWithChildren } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'

export const OverlayContainer: FC<PropsWithChildren<unknown>> = (props) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {props.children.map((child, index) => (
                <View style={styles.child} key={index}>
                    {child}
                </View>
            ))}
        </View>
    );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        height: '100%',
    },
    child: {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve this is with a negative margin.

```js
const deviceWidth = RN.Dimensions.get('window').width

a: {
  alignItems: 'center',
  backgroundColor: 'blue',
  width: deviceWidth,
},
b: {
  marginTop: -16,
  marginStart: 20,
},
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use elevation property for Android if you don't mind the shadow.

```
{
  elevation:1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
style = {{position: 'absolute', bottom: 20, left: 20, elevation: 100}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }} >
  <View style={{ height: Dimensions.get('window').height / 2, backgroundColor: 'blue', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
    <Text style={{ fontSize: 25, alignSelf: 'center' }} >A</Text>
      <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', height: 100, width: 100, backgroundColor: 'yellow', position: 'absolute', left: 20, top: Dimensions.get('window').height / 2 - 70 }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 22, alignSelf: 'center' }} >B</Text>
      </View>
  </View>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Position absolute for box B and put it on the bottom of JSX.

Most simple solution