# Adjust the zIndex of NavigatorIOS for React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Is it possible to adjust the z Index of the NavigatorIOS bar?

I want to have an object be swiped over the bar, but can't find a way to go over it, only under it.

This is specifically for the NavigatorIOS component and trying to get a draggable object to display over it instead of under.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In React Native, how do I put a view on top of another view, with part of it lying outside the bounds of the view behind?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31101445/in-react-native-how-do-i-put-a-view-on-top-of-another-view-with-part-of-it-lyi)

Comment: No good there. I'm using the NavigatorIOS component specifically here and trying to get a draggable object to display over it instead of under.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find a way to do this properly using the NavigatorIOS component, so I'll be using it to handle navigation still, but adding in a standard heading bar to show page titles and enable z index editing.