# Add subview in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I am new to react native and CSS in general and I am struggling to add a view that displays on top of a different one.

TL;DR: I need the text to appear as a title on top view. The circles are only the background. The playground with my code is in https://snack.expo.io/ryhODGSLU

This is the mock I am trying to implement:

[image]

---

**What I have tried:**

I've created the component:

```
class CirclesBackground extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.middleCircle}/>
        <View style={styles.topCircle}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

On top of it I want to display a text:

```
class Title extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text style={styles.titleText}>{this.props.text}</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

My App then puts the `Title` component inside of the `CirclesBackground` component:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
      <CirclesBackground>
        <Title text="Know when to go outside!"></Title>
      </CirclesBackground>
  );
}
```

**Problem??**

The text (the `Title` component) is not rendered. The circles are rendered correctly.

[image]

I have already tried using `position: "absolute"` and `zIndex: 5` like recommended in [In React Native, how do I put a view on top of another view, with part of it lying outside the bounds of the view behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31101445/in-react-native-how-do-i-put-a-view-on-top-of-another-view-with-part-of-it-lyi) but that has not solved it.

Can someone see what I am doing wrong?

---

Styles I am using:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  titleText: {
    fontSize: 28,
    textAlign: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    color: 'red',
    top: 100,
  },
  middleCircle: {
    overflow: 'hidden',
    width : 180,
    height:300,
    position : 'absolute',
    right: 0,
    borderTopLeftRadius:230,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 230,
    backgroundColor:'#F1E800',
    opacity: 0.4
  },
  topCircle: {
    overflow: 'hidden',
    width : 90,
    height:100,
    position : 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 80,
    backgroundColor:'#F1E800',
    opacity: 0.4
  }
});
```

And here the link to the playground: https://snack.expo.io/ryhODGSLU

Comment: what you mean by ```I need the text to appear on top of the circles```? could you explain that a bit more?

Comment: Hi @SDushan, thank you for asking. I have added an image of the mock I am trying to implement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a quick solution, you can pass your `Title` component as a child props to `CirclesBackground` as below

```
class CirclesBackground extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.middleCircle} />
        {this.props.children}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Now you can pass your `Title` component

```
<CirclesBackground>
  <Title text="Know when to go outside!"></Title>
</CirclesBackground>
```

This may not be the optimal solution.

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea one could pass a view as a prop. This is just the beginning of my view, should I create a component with all my other views (buttons, text, etc.) and pass it as a child to the `CirclesBackground`? 
Feel free to recommend me a tutorial that's helped you, a book. I am new to this and the tutorials I've found are either too basic or too advanced.

Comment: the answer to your question is ```yes```. But if you want to display circles as only a background image then it is better to use ```ImageBackground``` in react native.